# Assigning Value to Specific Object Key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to assign a value to a specific key in javascript named "AAPL".

However, when I assign this value, all my keys are getting assigned the same value.

My code below shows how I construct the object and assign the string value to [key].ticker.

```
var Underlying = [
  "FB",
  "AAPL"
  // ,
  // "AMZN",
  // "NFLX",
  // "GOOG",
  // "TWTR",
  // "BABA",
  // "TSLA",
  // "AMD",
  // "INTC",
  // "MSFT",
  // "RY",
  // "CM",
  // "BNS",
  // "TD",
  // "BMO"
];

const innerobj = {
  ticker: "",
  bidtype: "",
  asktype: "",
  price: "",
  size: "",
  timestamp: ""
};

const obj = Underlying.reduce(
  (o, key) => ({
    ...o,
    [key]: innerobj
  }),
  {}
);

obj["AAPL"].ticker = "AAPL";
console.log(obj);
```

However, the result I get is this:

```
{ FB:
    { ticker: 'AAPL',
      bidtype: '',
      asktype: '',
      price: '',
      size: '',
     timestamp: '' },
   AAPL:
   { ticker: 'AAPL',
      bidtype: '',
      asktype: '',
      price: '',
      size: '',
      timestamp: '' } }
```

I have tried many things. I appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you.

Comment: because they all share a reference to the same object.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ay2en198/